# nginx: Why SSL config on one domain enables the others?

Tags: nginx, ssl

Say I have `app1.domain.com` and `app2.domain.com`, and its basic config files `app1.conf` and `app2.conf`, inside `vhosts.d` folder.

SSL config files should contain the path of the app, and the path of the certs. However, why when adding SSL config only for app1 (`app1.ssl.conf`) enables SSL on app2? I mean, I can enter to https://app2.domain.com bringing the SSL key path from app1's SSL config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the configs you have specified, I'm going to make an educated guess.

In a non-SSL HTTP request, nginx knows what virtual server configuration you are requesting based on the HTTP `Host:` header that your browser sends. If you send a `Host:` header that doesn't match any of your virtual configurations, the server will send you to the default virtual server config or, lacking one configured, the "first" one (the "first" config is, I believe, either the first virtual server specified or the alphabetically first domain name).

In an SSL HTTP request, the effect is similar, except when your client makes a connection, the only way nginx knows which SSL certificate/key to use is by the Server Name Indicator (SNI) sent by your client. This happens before any Host: header is sent, SSL negotiation happening before any HTTP traffic is sent. If your client doesn't support the SNI extension or nginx can't find a configuration specifying a configuration that matches, nginx is going to default to, again, either the default virtual server or, lacking that, the "first" virtual server.

So, the reason it's happening is because you have a server configured to listen for SSL connections, and come hell or high water, nginx is going to respond to that request. The rest is nginx finding the best possible config to do so, and for the SSL connection, `app1.domain.com`'s SSL configuration is the only one available to it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It actually answer my question. However, I'm not sure why nginx uses that responsive policy. Suppose I have 10 sites on a single IP, running on different ports, and I want SSL on only one of them. I guess I should have to turn off SSL on every other vhost config.